# Using uncss with angular's ng-view directive

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, gruntjs

How do I use Addy Osmani's [uncss](http://addyosmani.com/blog/removing-unused-css/) while using Angular's ng-view directive.

Let's say I have a two views and I would like to use uncss. Using uncss tests if there are any unused styles on those views and creates a new style sheet.

**File Structure**
    - app

```
-styles
----- parts
      -----_bootstrap.scss
      -----_navigation.scss
----- main.scss

-views
----- home.html
----- about.html

-index.html
```

Unfortunately i am unable to make uncss work with `ng-view` directive because, I believe, it is async and the html hasnt been created yet.

**html index.html**

```
   <!-- /build -->
  </head>
  <body ng-app="navigationApp">
    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
    <div class="container" ng-view=""></div>
  </body>
```

**html home.html**

```
<div class="first"><h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero, ullam, impedit iste eaque deserunt quae dolorum atque labore nihil ut sunt repellendus inventore nulla. Expedita mollitia fugiat eveniet quasi ipsa.</h1></div>

<div class="second"><h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, pariatur, ex quod necessitatibus optio provident hic quasi dolorem molestiae similique velit accusamus id suscipit nesciunt ab repudiandae beatae praesentium dolores.</h2></div>

<div class="last"><p>asdl;fkjasdflkjas dflkajsdf;lkajsdf;lkj Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus, recusandae necessitatibus reprehenderit libero porro. Suscipit, soluta, reiciendis commodi vero consequatur officia veritatis pariatur iusto deleniti amet minima ducimus nostrum facilis.</p><div>
```

This example is meaningless, I'm just wondering if it's possible to make uncss work with angular ng-view or ui-router.  If so, how do I properly write the gruntfile?  If not, is there any solution?  Because this is a crazy awesome plugin.

**I have included it into my gruntfile.js**

```
// Generated on 2014-04-25 using generator-angular 0.8.0
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Load grunt tasks automatically
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    yeoman: {
      // configurable paths
      app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
      dist: 'dist'
    },

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
      bower: {
        files: ['bower.json'],
        tasks: ['bowerInstall']
      },
      js: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
        options: {
          livereload: true
        }
      },
      jsTest: {
        files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
      },
      compass: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        },
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
          '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ]
      }
    },

    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: 'localhost',
        livereload: 35729
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          base: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>'
          ]
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          port: 9001,
          base: [
            '.tmp',
            'test',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>'
          ]
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }
      }
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
      },
      all: [
        'Gruntfile.js',
        '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
      ],
      test: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
        },
        src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
      }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    autoprefixer: {
      options: {
        browsers: ['last 1 version']
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
    bowerInstall: {
      app: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
        ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/'
      },
      sass: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/'
      }
    },

    // Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
    compass: {
      options: {
        require: ['susy', 'breakpoint'],
        sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
        generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
        imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
        javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
        fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
        importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
        httpImagesPath: '/images',
        httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
        httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
        relativeAssets: false,
        assetCacheBuster: false,
        raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n'
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated'
        }
      },
      server: {
        options: {
          debugInfo: true
        }
      }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    rev: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          src: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
          ]
        }
      }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
      html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        flow: {
          html: {
            steps: {
              js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
              css: ['cssmin']
            },
            post: {}
          }
        }
      }
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
      }
    },

    // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
    cssmin: {
      options: {
        root: '<%= yeoman.app %>'
      }
    },

    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.svg',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
          removeOptionalTags: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: ['*.html', 'views/{,*/}*.html'],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },

    // ngmin tries to make the code safe for minification automatically by
    // using the Angular long form for dependency injection. It doesn't work on
    // things like resolve or inject so those have to be done manually.
    ngmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
          src: '*.js',
          dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Replace Google CDN references
    cdnify: {
      dist: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
      }
    },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            '.htaccess',
            '*.html',
            'views/{,*/}*.html',
            'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
            'fonts/*'
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/images',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
          src: ['generated/*']
        }]
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        dest: '.tmp/styles/',
        src: '{,*/}*.css'
      }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'compass:server'
      ],
      test: [
        'compass'
      ],
      dist: [
        'compass:dist',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin'
      ]
    },


    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
    // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
    // to use the Usemin blocks.
    // cssmin: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
    //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
    //         '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // uglify: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
    //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //   dist: {}
    // },
    uncss: {
        dist: {
          src: ['app/index.html'],
          dest: 'dist/css/tidy.css',
          options: {
            report: 'min' // optional: include to report savings
          }
        }
      },
    processhtml: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          'dist/index.html': ['app/index.html'],
          'dist/about.html': ['app/about.html']
        }
      }
    },
    // Test settings
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
      }
    }
  });


  grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'bowerInstall',
      'concurrent:server',
      'autoprefixer',
      'connect:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'concurrent:test',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:test',
    'karma'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'bowerInstall',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'ngmin',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'rev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin',
    'uncss'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
  // uncss: {
  //     dist: {
  //       src: ['app/about.html', 'app/index.html'],
  //       dest: 'dist/css/tidy.css',
  //       options: {
  //         report: 'min' // optional: include to report savings
  //       }
  //     }
  //   }
  //   processhtml: {
  //     dist: {
  //       files: {
  //         'dist/index.html': ['app/index.html'],
  //         'dist/about.html': ['app/about.html']
  //       }
  //     }
  //   }
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-uncss');

};
```

Answer (score 1):

**The `urls` option:**

Dynamic content can be addressed (to some degree) using the [urls](https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss#options) option that uncss offers.

You'll see in [the docs](https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss#what-do-the-options-do) that the `urls` option uses PhantomJS to render and parse a page to be uncss'ed. (Is that a word?)

There's mention of using [uncss with WordPress](https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss#what-do-the-options-do) and a link to a [walkthru](http://www.gladdy.co.uk/blog/2014/04/13/using-uncss-and-grunt-uncss-with-wordpress/) on how some to use uncss to walk a sitemap instead of a set of rendered files.

The downsides:

- It won't crawl your site or follow links.
- If the app's a [SPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) and you aren't using routes/HTML history/etc to feed uncss...

**An alternative:**

In my experience if I can `curl` a page, uncss is a pretty easy fit.  And, if I can `curl` it I could also just whip up a short script to walk the sitemap and dump the HTML to files and process those with uncss (which might be easier/faster/cheaper than maintaining the process the WordPress example illustrates if you don't have automated sitemaps, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, simply by iterating through the views, instead of just including index.html:

```
uncss: {
  dist: {
    src: ['app/index.html', 'app/views/**/*.html'],
    dest: 'dist/css/tidy.css',
    options: {
      report: 'min' // optional: include to report savings
    }
  }
}
```